# Which technologies are used to build Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Stack Overflow is really cool and all out.
What tools and that were used to build the site?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe this is a duplicate. The first time I've seen it today, but still a duplicate.

Comment: This question gets asked about once an hour.  Try searching.

Comment: PHP!? LOL [15 chars]

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

ASP.NET, C#, VS 2008, ASP.NET MVC, jQuery, SQL Server 2008, Subversion

Comment: what's up with the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the tech that makes it cool. It's the thought that goes into the design.

Worth reading Jeff's post here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001284.html